# UIButtonContent setImage: EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, image, crash, uibutton, exc-bad-access

So when I was testing my app, I am getting this crash in the console:

```
3   UIKit                           0x32fe529e -[UIButtonContent setImage:] + 26
4   UIKit                           0x32fe51dc -[UIButton setImage:forState:] + 136
5   App                         0x0005ce20 -[MainView resetPicture] (MainView.mm:138)
```

So I checked MainView's resetPicture and this is the code at or around line 138:

```
if ([myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] != theImage) {
      [myButton setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Now I do this to theImage in the ViewDidLoad:

```
nib = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My-Image-Button.png"];
```

Now is there anything here that could be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of object is `theImage`?

Comment: Do you have NSZombies on? If not, try turning it on and see what happens.

Comment: Does `theImage` exist? How about `myButton`.

Comment: @Jesse and Zaph, the issue is that I personally cannot even reproduce it on my iOS 6 iPhone 5, my tester whom doesn't live locally is on an iOS 5.0.1 iPhone 4S has this issue. So I wouldn't even know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ARC? If not, then you'd need to retain the UIImage you're loading when storing it in an instance variable as your code shows. (Or use a property.) Otherwise, it could be deallocated by the time you get to resetPicture.

Comment: I am not using ARC, this would've been my next guess so I am presuming this was the issue since it was in fact a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.